# Amazon Flexible Payments Service (Amazon FPS) IPN Verification PHP IPNVerificationSampleCode.php

Tags: payment

```
<?php
/** 
 *  PHP Version 5
 *
 *  @category    Amazon
 *  @package     Amazon_FPS
 *  @copyright   Copyright 2008-2011 Amazon Technologies, Inc.
 *  @link        http://aws.amazon.com
 *  @license     http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0  Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  @version     2010-08-28
 */
/******************************************************************************* 
 *    __  _    _  ___ 
 *   (  )( \/\/ )/ __)
 *   /__\ \    / \__ \
 *  (_)(_) \/\/  (___/
 * 
 *  Amazon FPS PHP5 Library
 *  Generated: Wed Sep 23 03:35:04 PDT 2009
 * 
 */

require_once '.config.inc.php';
require_once 'Amazon/IpnReturnUrlValidation/SignatureUtilsForOutbound.php';

class Amazon_FPS_IPNVerificationSampleCode {

    public static function test() {

        $utils = new Amazon_FPS_SignatureUtilsForOutbound();

        //Parameters present in ipn.
        $params["TransactionId"] = "17UD7UO16UVR84O88ZMHJ1QUMDE1GFETHOE";
        $params["TransactionDate"] = "1372686606";
        $params["Status"] = "SUCCESS";
        $params["NotificationType"] = "TransactionStatus";
        $params["CallerReference"] = "callerReference=ReferenceString51d18879000f4";
        $params["Operation"] = "PAY";
        $params["TransactionAmount"] = "USD 5.00";
        $params["BuyerName"] = "prabhnoor";
        $params["PaymentMethod"] = "CC";
        $params["PaymentReason"] = "DescriptionString-1251832057319108";
        $params["RecipientEmail"] = "zoccusmed@gmail.com";
        $params["SignatureMethod"] = "RSA-SHA1";
        $params["SignatureVersion"] = "2";
        $params["CertificateUrl"] = "https://fps.sandbox.amazonaws.com/certs/090911/PKICert.pem";
        $params["Signature"] = "Mmyahn7nFpOhYgg76orkNv88Psw4is3H9fHIC0VUdNA"
                               ."PaT81jGIKgLezCk/z2xSpacot3NzhGUw9"
                               ."f18nXR1dFSDItu2AHYEtcZ9efeEqo73H"
                               ."lQxG0ysnIOjuXTX3K2gqBlAFnVHTmcADTDUKHfceqm2H"
                               ."w8wf+oz+Er8zCY58uFw=";

        $urlEndPoint = "http://www.dekhfashion.com/testamazon/test/ipn/"; //Your url end point receiving the ipn.

        print "Verifying IPN signed using signature v2 ....\n";
        //IPN is sent as a http POST request and hence we specify POST as the http method.
        //Signature verification does not require your secret key
        print "Is signature correct: " . $utils->validateRequest($params, $urlEndPoint, "POST") . "\n";
    }
}

Amazon_FPS_IPNVerificationSampleCode::test(); 
?>
```

If this gives Invalid signature error

Keep all the variables first letter capital it will start workiing ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put correct
define('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);

it will word correct

also change

Introduction:

Amazon FPS sends you outbound notifications in the form of GET and POST on your ReturnURL and IPN endpoints respectively. When you handle these notifications, we recommend you to validate the signature to ensure that the notification actually originated from us. You can validate the signature using signature version 2 with a server-side call to the VerifySignature API. In this call, you send the entire URL including the HTTP parameters received to FPS VerifySignature API and it will return a Boolean that indicates whether the signature was validated. Samples using this API to validate the signature are included in the src/com/amazonaws/ipnreturnurlvalidation folder. Their usage is described below.
Package Content
Directory   Overview
src/Amazon/FPS  All sources including code samples that demonstrate making FPS calls.
src/Amazon/IpnReturnUrlValidation   All sources including code samples that demonstrate validation of ipn and return url notifications.
Verifying Incoming Signatures
Steps to validate Return URL

```
Go to src/Amazon/IpnReturnUrlValidation/Samples directory and open ReturnUrlVerificationSampleCode.php
In function test, replace/add the parameters you received at your return url and also update urlEndPoint to your return url end point.

        $utils = new Amazon_FPS_SignatureUtilsForOutbound();

        //Parameters present in return url.
        $params["expiry"] = "10/2013";
        $params["tokenID"] = "Q5IG5ETFCEBU8KBLTI4JHINQVL6VAJVHICBRR49AKLPIEZH1KB1S8C7VHAJJMLJ3";
        $params["status"] = "SC";
        $params["callerReference"] = "1253247023946cMcrTRrjtLjNrZGNKchWfDtUEIGuJfiOBAAJYPjbytBV";
        $params["signatureMethod"] = "RSA-SHA1";
        $params["signatureVersion"] = "2";
        $params["certificateUrl"] = "https://fps.amazonaws.com/certs/090909/PKICert.pem";
        $params["signature"] = "H4NTAsp3YwAEiyQ86j5B53lksv2hwwEaEFxtdWFpy9xX764AZy/Dm0RLEykUUyPVLgqCOlMopay5"
          . "Qxr/VDwhdYAzgQzA8VCV8x9Mn0caKsJT2HCU6tSLNa6bLwzg/ildCm2lHDho1Xt2yaBHMt+/Cn4q"
          . "I5B+6PDrb8csuAWxW/mbUhk7AzazZMfQciJNjS5k+INlcvOOtQqoA/gVeBLsXK5jNsTh09cNa7pb"
          . "gAvey+0DEjYnIRX+beJV6EMCPZxnXDGo0fA1PENLWXIHtAoIJAfLYEkVbT2lva2tZ0KBBWENnSjf"
          . "26lMZVokypIo4huoGaZMp1IVkImFi3qC6ipCrw==";

        $urlEndPoint = "http://www.mysite.com/call_pay.jsp"; //Your return url end point. 
        print "Verifying return url signed using signature v2 ....\n";
        //return url is sent as a http GET request and hence we specify GET as the http method.
        //Signature verification does not require your secret key
        print "Is signature correct: " . $utils->validateRequest($params, $urlEndPoint, "GET") . "\n";


Run the sample and make sure the signature is valid.
```

Steps to validate IPN posts

```
Go to src/Amazon/IpnReturnUrlValidation/Samples directory and open IpnVerificationSampleCode.php
In function test, replace/add the parameters that you got in your IPN post. Also, set the urlEndPoint to your IPN end point.

        $utils = new Amazon_FPS_SignatureUtilsForOutbound();

        //Parameters present in ipn.
        $params["transactionId"] = "14DRG2JGR7LK4J54P544DKKNDLQFFZLE323";
        $params["transactionDate"] = "1251832057";
        $params["status"] = "INITIATED";
        $params["notificationType"] = "TransactionStatus";
        $params["callerReference"] = "callerReference=ReferenceStringJYI1251832057319108";
        $params["operation"] = "PAY";
        $params["transactionAmount"] = "USD 1.00";
        $params["buyerName"] = "BuyerName-SsUo3oDjHx";
        $params["paymentMethod"] = "CC";
        $params["paymentReason"] = "DescriptionString-1251832057319108";
        $params["recipientEmail"] = "recipientemail@amazon.com";
        $params["signatureMethod"] = "RSA-SHA1";
        $params["signatureVersion"] = "2";
        $params["certificateUrl"] = "https://fps.amazonaws.com/certs/090909/PKICert.pem";
        $params["signature"] = "vKXXCbtxvSkRR+Zn8YNW6DNGpbi474h2iM4L+xaOi16kYKdYpuGbvKyXQ36uTZTVHdUGAAcvpXFL"
                . "wDfnTcqcckr2IUElrVJKQeT0WeWR+IqmABwSRGo+YqjzPNISSNXNzg6LFhouhUvmmwY15X3YgXfc"
                . "ERN5IhPwv04YkyCLPCA9P0/QgD8Jum/hc9jj0HYjj3s3MuuQ3yoIhf2x+2CBZRm5lslRqnoF/8OJ"
                . "1ZHmAHt9VvQSZ+QC3fwJgeqzJPAvtuOm930BP6hPYZVhXE5w7ByLt0qLk1ZFE/vzQ4io4vOyie6W"
                . "bhp5+AuNyAs+QrGMYO8VZruZJfkZO4b6QOgV2A==";

        $urlEndPoint = "http://www.mysite.com/ipn.jsp"; //Your url end point receiving the ipn.

        print "Verifying IPN signed using signature v2 ....\n";
        //IPN is sent as a http POST request and hence we specify POST as the http method.
        //Signature verification does not require your secret key
        print "Is signature correct: " . $utils->validateRequest($params, $urlEndPoint, "POST") . "\n";


Run the sample make sure the signature is valid.
```

Summary of the steps to use Server side validation for Return URL and IPN:

1

Capture the notification on your IPN endpoint

2

Pass all the parameters to the validateRequest method of SignatureUtilsForOutbound

3

Capture the boolean returned by the validateRequest method and process the IPN or discard based on its value

About the library

```
Based on the 2010-08-28 API version.
Version: 2.1
Release Date: 2012-10-01
```

Before you begin

Extract the contents of amazon-fps-2010-08-28-php5-library.zip to a folder. The folder "amazon-fps-2010-08-28-php5-library" will be created. This folder will be referred to as  from this point onwards. This folder should contain the following sub-directories:

```
src — This folder contains the code files for the library and sample API calls to Amazon FPS.
```

Prerequisites

```
Amazon FPS Sandbox Account (Click here to sign up).
Amazon FPS Developer Account (Click here to sign up).
You must have PHP version 5.2.6 or later installed
You must have cURL version 7.26 or later installed
```

Configuration

```
Update the keys required to make the API call. This is one time activity and should be same for all APIs
    Goto <ROOT>/src/Amazon/FPS/Samples directory
    Open the .config.inc.php file
    Change the following two lines and save the file
        define('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '<Your aws access key>');
        define('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '<Your aws secret key>');
Update the FPS/CBUI endpoints (only required for sandbox environment, for prodouction no changes are required)
    Open the CBUIPipeline.php file
    Change the following line if needed and save the file
        protected static $CBUI_URL = "https://authorize.payments-sandbox.amazon.com/cobranded-ui/actions/start";
    Open the Client.php file
    Change the following line if needed and save the file
        private $_config = array ('ServiceURL' ='https://fps.sandbox.amazonaws.com')
```

Steps to make a payment

Making a payment involves two parts. First, you obtain a payment authorization from buyers by redirecting them to co-branded pages hosted by Amazon FPS. When buyers return to your web site, you receive a payment authorization(also called a sender token) as part of the return URL. Second, you use this payment authorization or sender token in a 'Pay' API call to make a payment.
Steps to get authrorization from buyer

```
Setup an app server at your side to receive HTTP redirect from Cobranded UI.
Get the authorization from the buyer
    Go to <ROOT>/src/Amazon/CBUI/Samples directory and open CBUISingleUsePipelineSample.php
    In function test, set the following fields

    $pipeline = new Amazon_FPS_CBUISingleUsePipeline(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
    $pipeline->setMandatoryParameters("callerReferenceSingleUse",
                    "http://www.mysite.com/call_back.jsp", "5");

    //optional parameters
    $pipeline->addParameter("currencyCode", "USD");
    $pipeline->addParameter("paymentReason", "HarryPotter 1-5 DVD set");

    //SingleUse url
    print "Sample CBUI url for SingleUse pipeline : " . $pipeline->getUrl() . "\n";


    Run this smaple and copy the URL printed on console and paste it on your browser. You will be redirected to Amazon FPS CBUI
    Go through the pipeline. Make sure you use a different Amazon FPS account, while acting as buyer. At the end of the pipeline, you(buyer) will be redirected back to the return URL provided in the query string above.
    The return URL will include expiry, tokenID, status, callerReference and signature parameters. Please note that tokenID will be used in Pay later.
    Validate that Amazon Payments CBUI actually redirected the customer to the Return URL specified. We use server-side validation using VerifySignature API call. Click here for steps.
Steps to make a payment
    Open PaySample.php in <ROOT>/src/Amazon/FPS/Samples
    Replace the following line

     // @TODO: set request. Action can be passed as Amazon_FPS_Model_PayRequest

    with the code snippet below:

    $request =  new Amazon_FPS_Model_PayRequest();
    $request->setSenderTokenId('A12345666666BCDEFFF');//set the proper senderToken here.
    $amount = new Amazon_FPS_Model_Amount();
    $amount->setCurrencyCode("USD");
    $amount->setValue('1'); //set the transaction amount here;
    $request->setTransactionAmount($amount);
    $request->setCallerReference('CallerReference123456789'); //set the unique caller reference here.


    Set SenderTokenId the same as the one returned by CBUI above
    Run php PaySample.php to make the pay API call. You should see the output similar to the following:

    PayResponse
       PayResult
          TransactionId
              13L1AFBDB54MM68LBL8UDPJTQOZNP1F3PTC
                  TransactionStatus
                      Pending
                         ResponseMetadata
                             RequestId
                                 85b069ef-8b27-43e1-89cf-f1cfcb3a0e72:0
                                 ...


    Experiment with other samples, examine samples sources. When ready, add library project to your solution, and use it.
    If the response status is Pending, you can use GetTransactionStatus API to get latest transaction status
    Amazon Payments will post an IPN for this transaction to your ipn url registered with us. We use server-side validation using VerifySignature API call . Click here for steps.
```

Related resources
More about Amazon FPS
Documentation
Code samples
Contact us for technical issues
Comments, Questions or Feedback
If you have any comments, questions or feedback on the library, please start discussion here (Amazon FPS forum).